# Question about a noun: Correct wording

Tags: questions

"Her eyes are beautiful."

I want to ask about her eyes, to put a question to the attributive. What is the correct wording of my question? Thanks.

Comment: "Are her eyes beautiful?"

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't really about the noun—you know about her **eyes**. It's about the adjective—the description of her eyes.

A 'closed' question—one which prompts the answer 'Yes' or 'No'—is easy: you simply 'invert' the subject and the auxiliary verb *BE*:

> Are her eyes beautiful?  —*Yes, they are*.

But for an 'open' question—one which accepts any adjective or adjectival as answer—you have to start your question with a *wh-* word. And that gets a little tricky. In English we have interrogative pronouns (*wh-* words like *who, what, which* which invite nominal answers) and interrogative pro-adverbs (*wh-* words like *where, when, why, how* which invite adverbial answers), but we don't have interrogative pro-adjectives or pro-verbs. For verb or adjective interrogatives we have to use constructions with a pronoun plus a verb phrase. Usually the pronoun is *what*—

> **What** did she **do**? asks for a verb answer: *She rose/sat/danced*
>   **What** do her eyes **look like**? asks for an adjective answer: *They're blue/black/beautiful*
>   **What are** her eyes **like**? licenses an answer that goes beyond the eyes' visual appearance: *They're like raisins in a cupcake.*

With adjectives there is also a construction using the pro-adverb *how*:

> **How** do her eyes **look**?

But this is usually reserved for situations when you're asking about temporary appearance, not the usual appearance—for instance, if you know she suffered an injury which may have affected her eyes and you want to know her current condition.

*How* is also used to ask about the degree of a particular quality; but in this case it serves as an ordinary pro-adverb qualifying an adjective and asks for an adverbial answer.

> **How** beautiful are her eyes? —*Her eyes are **somewhat** beautiful*.

Comment: @Araucaria Thengewp.

Comment: My pledger entierly..

Comment: You forgot plain *What are her eyes **like**?*. Without ***look***, that version is a much more "generic" way of asking for information *about* something, since it works for things like *What's her voice like?* (i.e. - it's not inherently limited to contexts where you're only asking about the visual appearance of something).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point -- I'll add it.

Comment: Curiously, although ***He looks like trouble*** is perfectly valid, I think that would inevitably have to be seen as a somewhat facetious reply to ***What does he look like?*** (but it could be completely natural in response to ***What's he like?***).